# "Ops" group generic method and match.call for delayed evaluation

Tags: r

I am playing with custom indicator syntax language (ISL) to design and evaluate trading rules.

I want to define basic binary operator methods for my custom class `indicator`. Operations on the `indicator`, such as `>=`,`<=` etc., once evaluated, will have binary output (either zeroes or ones), stored in another object of class `signal`. `signal` object should also hold the definition of the operation (unevaluated expression) for delayed evaluation.

My attempt:

```
### define classes

indicator <- function ()  {
  structure(NULL, class="indicator")
}

signal <- function (definition)  {
  structure(NULL, call=definition, class="signal")
}

`Ops.indicator` <- function(x, y, ...) {
  .call <- match.call()
  ret <- signal(definition=.call)
}

### create unevaluated definitions of indicators and signals

ind <- indicator()
sig <- ind <= 2
```

Structure of the object `str(sig)` is:

```
 list()
 - attr(*, "call")= language Ops.indicator(x = ind, y = 2)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "signal"
```

whereas I would need to store specific expression with `<=`, to evaluate later:

```
 list()
 - attr(*, "call")= language `<=.indicator`(x = ind, y = 2)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "signal"
```

How to rewrite `Ops.indicator` to achieve this, without having to repeat code in the 6 separate indicator methods for "==", "!=", "<", "<=", ">=", ">"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
indicator <- function ()  {
  structure(list(), class="indicator")
}

binary_op <- function(op, x, y)  {
  structure(list(op = op, x = x, y = y), class = "binary_signal")
}

`Ops.indicator` <- function(x, y, ...) {
  binary_op(.Generic, substitute(x), substitute(y))
}

ind <- indicator()
sig <- ind <= 2
```

The key is to use the special `.Generic` value, but I also made a couple of other small tweaks:

- You'll find S3 objects easier to use if you base them on list elements rather than attributes
- NULL is a singleton, so assigning attributes to it silently coerces it to `list()`
- I think the objects will probably be easier to work with if you store the individual pieces rather than the complete call.

Finally, you might want to read more about [domain specific languages in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/dsl.html).

Comment: I don't know if this is essential but the arguments to group generic operators will be evaluated. I had to try to believe but while Hadley's solution will return unevaluated expressions, nonetheless they have already been evaluated once and any side effects will take place, even if the result is only used for method dispatch.

Comment: @piccolbo yeah, arguments to generics (not just group) used for method dispatch must always be evaluated - otherwise how could R find the right method?

Comment: It actually evaluates both args, so I am not sure what the rationale is, but it's documented. I just wanted to warn the OP if the evaluation is costly or has side effects. In my application, arguments can't be evaluated unless they are first manipulated, so it's a blocker, I resorted to using %|%.